# Persisting Entity Framework nested/related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entities:

```
public class ModuleCriteria
{
    public int ModuleCriteriaId { get; set; }

    public string Criteria { get; set; }

    public List<ModuleCriteriaLookup> ModuleCriteriaLookups { get; set; 
}
}

public class ModuleCriteriaLookup
{
    public int ModuleCriteriaLookupId { get; set; }

    public int ModuleCriteriaId { get; set; } // ** (Foreign Key) **

    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public ModuleCriteria ModuleCriteria { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following EF configuration in my `Context` class (edited for brevity):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<ModuleCriteriaLookup>().HasRequired( mc => mc.ModuleCriteria );

    // I tried adding the below line but it made no difference.
    //modelBuilder.Entity<ModuleCriteria>().HasMany( mc => mc.ModuleCriteriaLookups );
}
```

...and I have the following `DbSet` properties defined in my `Context` class:

```
public DbSet<ModuleCriteria> ModuleCriteria { get; set; }

public DbSet<ModuleCriteriaLookup> ModuleCriteriaLookup { get; set; }
```

I have a `CriteriaRepository` class, which has a `Save` method, for persisting changes for my `ModuleCriteria` entities:

```
public void Save( ModuleCriteria moduleCriteria )
{
    using ( var ctx = new MyAppContext() )
    {
        ctx.Entry( moduleCriteria ).State = moduleCriteria.ModuleCriteriaId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

A `ModuleCriteria` object can exist without a `ModuleCriteriaLookup` object, but  `ModuleCriteriaLookup` object has to relate to an existing `ModuleCriteria` object (related on `ModuleCriteriaId`).

You can have multiple `ModuleCriteraLookup` objects all relating to the same one `ModuleCriteria` object.

The behaviour that I would like, and expect with EF, is:

1) If I create a new `ModuleCriteria` object (without any `ModuleCriteriaLookups`), call the `Save` method in my repository, I would expect to see new `ModuleCriteria` record in the db with no related `ModuleCriteriaLookup` records in the db.

2) If I create a new `ModuleCriteria` object and assign a `List<ModuleCriteriaLookup>` to it, call the Save method in my repository, I would expect to see new `ModuleCriteria` record in the db and x new `ModuleCriteriaLookup` rows in the db which relate to that particular `ModuleCriteria`.

3) If I add/edit/remove any of the `ModuleCriteriaLookup` objects that related to one of my `ModuleCriteria` objects, then call the `Save` method in my repository, I would expect to see any of the `ModuleCriteria`'s deleted `ModuleCriteriaLookup` objects to get removed from the db, any new ones added and any edited ones simply to get updated.

So all I ever need worry about is that whatever the `ModuleCriteria.ModuleCriteriaLookups` property contains for a given `ModuleCriteria`, that's what will be reflected in the 2 tables in my DB by simply calling the Save method for the `ModuleCriteria` object in my repository.

Unfortunately at the moment, if I'm adding a new `ModuleCriteria` object with associated `List<ModuleCriteriaLookup>` it adds both `ModuleCriteria` and x `ModuleCriteriaLookup` rows in the db nicely. But when I want to edit or delete entries in the `ModuleCriteria.ModuleCriteriaLookups` property, this is not being reflected in the db. Nothing is happening with the `ModuleCriteriaLookups` rows.

I'm not sure where exactly the problem is, whether its whether the EF mapping configuration, or something to do with how the repository works?

Comment: @Irshad please watch it with your suggested edit streak that adds `inline code` to posts. It doesn't always make it more readable.

Comment: Where during the model configuration are you specifying that ModuleCriteriaId is the FK to ModuleCriteria? I did not see that in your OnModelCreating method. It might be worth adding in 

`modelBuilder.Entity<ModuleCriteriaLookup>().HasRequired( mc => mc.ModuleCriteria).WithMany(m => m.ModuleCriteriaLookup).HasForeignKey(mc => mc.ModuleCriteriaId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: @DDiVita He doesnt' need to, naming conventions will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is located in the repository. The `DbContext` needs to be aware of the existence of entities. So when editing and/or deleting entities the entities need to be fetched from the database first.

This [description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696410(v=vs.113).aspx) clearly states:

> The `.Entry` property returns objects from the context that are being
>   tracked by the context.

Because you directly use this properties right after creating the context, the context isn't tracking these entities and is therefore not aware that something has changed. And thereby is unable to generate the correct SQL statements.

There are several ways to deal with this, depending on the rest of your design.

One way to delete it would be:

```
    public void DeleteModuleCriteriaLookup(ModuleCriteriaLookup[] lookups)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyAppContext())
        {
            var moduleCriteriaId = lookups.First().ModuleCriteriaId;

            var moduleCritria = (
                from criteria in ctx.ModuleCriteria
                where criteria.ModuleCriteriaId == moduleCriteriaId
                select criteria
                ).Single();

            var lookupIdsToDelete = lookups.Select(l => l.ModuleCriteriaLookupId);

            var lookupsToDelete = (
                from lookup in moduleCritria.ModuleCriteriaLookups
                where lookupIdsToDelete.Contains(lookup.ModuleCriteriaLookupId)
                select lookup
                ).ToArray();

            foreach (var lookup in lookupsToDelete)
            {
                moduleCritria.ModuleCriteriaLookups.Remove(lookup);
            }

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```